# Do I need webstarter in order to use just RestController annotation?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-boot-starter

I have seen an Spring Boot web starter example on the web that includes the starter just to employ Restcontroller annotation, but I am doing the small poc and I can see that I do not need it...I am missing something or adding the starter was indeed  an overkill in this example that I saw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `@RestController` in your PoC, you must include `spring-boot-starter-web` artifact into the classpath.